# How can I get the "columnDefs" properties of a jquery datatable?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I wanna get the targets bellow to use on a separate function:

```
{
    "targets": [ 4,5,6,7,10,11,14,15 ],
    "visible": false,
    "searchable": false
},
```

**UPDATE**

The answer:

```
var table = $('#table').DataTable();
table.init().columnDefs[0].targets;
```

[Got it here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34006473/how-turn-on-columndefs-in-jquery-datatable)
Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer:

```
var table = $('#table').DataTable();
table.init().columnDefs[0].targets;
```

[Got it here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34006473/how-turn-on-columndefs-in-jquery-datatable)

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple to create an options object outside of a plugin function call....and just pass the whole object to that plugin function.

```
var tableOpts = {
    "targets": [ 4,5,6,7,10,11,14,15 ],
    "visible": false,
    "searchable": false
};    

$(selector).Datatables( tableOpts );
```

Then somewhere else in the code:

```
alert( tableOpts.searchable)
```